# Analytic of point

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have a Problem with analytic of point
A(1/2,-3) and B(a,2a) are given if $AB^2$=3/4 find the sum of possible values of a
How can we square B ? Is $AB^2$ a line or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have $$\vec{AB}=\left[a-\frac{1}{2};2a+3\right]$$ so we get $$(\vec{AB})^2=\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+(2a+3)^2=\frac{3}{4}$$ this is the dot product
and must be solved for $a$
$$\vec{AB}=[x_B-x_A;y_B-y_A]$$

Comment: I am new to analytic geometry can you explain how you get AB?

Comment: can you proceed now?

Comment: Can you please write the formula of dot product too?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product